# Laraver - display model structure

Tags: laravel

Im learning laravel.

My question is about some simple way do display model structure. I have little experience with django and as i remember, structure for each model was placed inside model files.

Yet in laravel, i need to put starting structure inside migration file:

```
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->string('name')->default('');
```

Then if i want to add some new field, i will place this field in next migration file, etc.

So, is there any way to see some kind of summary for model? Maybe some bash command for tinker?

Comment: Did you try using `var_dump` on the instance of the model? should show you all columns withing the attribute property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a bunch of options for you to choose from.

If you would like to show a summary of a model while you are in `tinker`, you can call `toArray()` on an instance of your model.

Ex:

```
$ php artisan tinker;

>>> $user = new App\User(['email' => 'john@doe.com', 'password' => 'password]);
>>> $user->toArray();
```

If you are trying to see a summary of a model displayed on your webpage, just `var_dump` or `dd(...)` an instance of your model after calling `toArray()` on it, and you'll get the same result as above, just in your web browser.

If you are looking for a way to show the table structure without creating any Model instances, you can display the table structure in your terminal, the exact command depending on what database you are using.

For example in MySQL you would do something like:

```
mysql> show COLUMNS from USERS;
```

It might also be a good idea to get a GUI app, I like [Sequel Pro](http://www.sequelpro.com) (for Mac).

P.S. I would just add that you should only have separate migrations for adding new fields when you are already in production and can't lose data from your database. While you are still in development and don't care about your data, it is much better to call `php artisan migrate:rollback`, add the new field to your `create` migration, and then `php artisan migrate` again, rather than making tons of new migration files.